# How to factorize two data frame meanwhile with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame, one is user-item-rating and the other is side information of the items:

```
#df1
A12VH45Q3H5R5I B000NWJTKW 5.0
A3J8AQWNNI3WSN B000NWJTKW 4.0
A1XOBWIL4MILVM BDASK99000 1.0

#df2
B000NWJTKW ....
BDASK99000 ....
```

Now I w'd like to map the name of item and user to integer ID. I know there is a way of `factorize`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
```

But I 'd like to ensure that the integer of the items in two data frame are consistent. So the resulting data frames is:

```
#df1
1       1      5.0
2       1      4.0
3       2      1.0

#df2
1      ...
2      ...
```

Do you know how to ensure that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the common column(s), and apply `pd.factorize` (or `pd.Categorical`) on that:

```
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(pd.concat([df1['item'], df2['item']]))
df1['item'] = codes[:len(df1)] + 1
df2['item'] = codes[len(df1):] + 1
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
[('A12VH45Q3H5R5I', 'B000NWJTKW', 5.0),
 ('A3J8AQWNNI3WSN', 'B000NWJTKW', 4.0),
 ('A1XOBWIL4MILVM', 'BDASK99000', 1.0)], columns=['user', 'item', 'rating'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
[('B000NWJTKW', 10),
 ('BDASK99000', 20)], columns=['item', 'extra'])

codes, uniques = pd.factorize(pd.concat([df1['item'], df2['item']]))
df1['item'] = codes[:len(df1)] + 1
df2['item'] = codes[len(df1):] + 1

codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df1['user'])
df1['user'] = codes + 1

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

yields

```
# df1
   user  item  rating
0     1     1       5
1     2     1       4
2     3     2       1

# df2
   item  extra
0     1     10
1     2     20
```

---

Another way to work-around the problem (if you have enough memory) would be to merge the two DataFrames: `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='item', how='outer')`, and then factorize `df3['item']`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='item', how='outer')
for col in ['item', 'user']:
    df3[col] = pd.factorize(df3[col])[0] + 1
print(df3)
```

yields

```
   user  item  rating  extra
0     1     1       5     10
1     2     1       4     10
2     3     2       1     20
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to apply factorize on the first dataframe, and then apply the resulting mapping to the second dataframe:

```
# create factorization:
idx, levels = pd.factorize(df1['item'])

# replace the item codes in the first dataframe with the new index value
df1['item'] = idx

# create a dictionary mapping the original code to the new index value
d = {code: i for i, code in enumerate(codes)}

# apply this mapping to the second dataframe
df2['item'] = df2.item.apply(lambda code: d[code])
```

This approach will only work if every level is present in both dataframes.